# Is there a way to avoid this infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Im stuck in an infinite loop, and I cant turn around this problem. I hope someone helps me.

So I have two columns, one is called " regular price " the second " multiplier "

I need to check if the regular price changes, the multiplier must change aswell, and vice versa, if the multiplier changes the regular price must change.

this is the nearest solution I found for this problem (it works tho, but it dies) :

```
jQuery('.column-yith_wcbep_cf_multiplicador').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
  var tabela1 = document.getElementsByClassName("yith_wcbep_products")[0].rows
  var arrayMultiplicador1 = []

  
  for (k = 1;  k < tabela1.length -1; k ++){
        var multiplicadorNovo1 = tabela1[k].childNodes[10].innerHTML
        var pvaNovo1 = tabela1[k].childNodes[11].innerHTML
        var regularPriceNovo1 = tabela1[k].childNodes[5].innerHTML
        var numeroPVA1 = Number(pvaNovo1)
        var numeroRegularPrice1 = Number(regularPriceNovo1)
        var numeroMultiplicador1 = Number(multiplicadorNovo1)
        var novoResultado1 = numeroRegularPrice1 / numeroPVA1
        // tabela1[k].childNodes[10].innerHTML = novoResultado;
        var multiplicadorAll1 = tabela1[k].childNodes[10].innerHTML
        arrayMultiplicador1.push(multiplicadorAll1)
        var resultadroRegPrice1 = numeroMultiplicador1 * numeroPVA1
        tabela1[k].childNodes[5].innerHTML = resultadroRegPrice1.toFixed(2)

        
        
    }
});

jQuery('.regular_price').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
var tabela = document.getElementsByClassName("yith_wcbep_products")[0].rows

    var arrayMultiplicador = []
    var ids = []
    for (i = 1;  i < tabela.length -1; i ++){
        var multiplicadorNovo = tabela[i].childNodes[10].innerHTML
        var pvaNovo = tabela[i].childNodes[11].innerHTML
        var regularPriceNovo = tabela[i].childNodes[5].innerHTML
        var numeroPVA = Number(pvaNovo)
        var numeroRegularPrice = Number(regularPriceNovo)
        var numeroMultiplicador = Number(multiplicadorNovo)
        var novoResultado = numeroRegularPrice / numeroPVA
        tabela[i].childNodes[10].innerHTML = novoResultado;
        var multiplicadorAll = tabela[i].childNodes[10].innerHTML
        arrayMultiplicador.push(multiplicadorAll)
        // var resultadroRegPrice = numeroMultiplicador * numeroPVA
            // tabela[i].childNodes[5].innerHTML = resultadroRegPrice.toFixed(2)

        
        
    }
});
```

What is happening is when I change one of the columns, the other column also changes and it turns into an infinite loop, the console gets full of errors and the site crashes - https://prnt.sc/uq6wm9

What can I do to prevent this?

Thanks.

Comment: One thing, whether or not this is the problem, is that your loop variables (`k`, `i`) must be declared with `let` or `var`.

Comment: Also either use jQuery or don't; mixing native DOM APIs with jQuery is a recipe for bugs.